# How to copy the output from command line on to shared memory?

Tags: c, linux, command-line, shared-memory

The child process takes a number n from on command line where n is the number of students. The data of students (name and marks) is entered on command window.

Now this data is to be copied in shared memory. This is what I'm having trouble with.
The parent process is to then take this data from shared memory and copy in a file.

'''

```
struct student {
                char name[20];
                float marks;
               };
               
               
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
key_t key = 10;
int shmID =shmget(key, 100, 0666 | IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL);
pid_t pid;
pid=fork();
if(pid==0)
{
//Child writes data of n number of students
char* child_at = (char*) shmat (shmID,NULL,0);

    char name[50];
    int marks,i,n;
    int a = 0;
    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    struct student stuarr[n];
    printf("Number of students: %d\n",n);
    
    
    for (i=0;i<n;++i) 
    {
        printf("For student %d\nEnter name: ",i+1);
        scanf("%s",stuarr[i].name);
        
        printf("Enter marks: ");
        scanf("%f",&stuarr[i].marks);
            
    }
    printf("\n\tName\tMarks\t\n");
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
                printf("\t%s\t%.2f\t\n", stuarr[i].name, stuarr[i].marks);


    
    for (i=0;i<n;++i) 
    {
    
    //STUCK HERE. How do I copy the output from command line on to shared memory???

    //child_at[a]=(char)&stuarr[i];
    //a++;
    }
    

    
}

else if (pid>0)
{
//Parent creates shared memory, waits. Then writes data of students to file
char* parent_at = shmat(shmID, NULL, 0);
wait(NULL);
int i, n = atoi(argv[1]);
struct student stuarr[n];
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr=(fopen("student.txt","w"));
    if(fptr==NULL) 
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i=0;i<n;++i) 
    {
        fprintf(fptr,"\nName: %s \nMarks=%.2f \n",stuarr[i].name,stuarr[i].marks);
    }
    
    fclose(fptr);
    int d2 =shmdt(parent_at);
    shmctl(shmID, IPC_RMID, NULL);

}
}
```

'''

Comment: Try `memcpy(child_at + (a * sizeof(struct student)), &stuarr[i], sizeof(struct student));`

Comment: Ok I will. Thank you